# CursorWrapper has 0 rows

Tags: java, android, sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem getting "question"objects from my SQLitedatabase with a custom CursorWrapper. I use a query function which returns the CursorWrapper with all rows with questions which have the given chapter index and which learned integer is 0. There must be a syntax error I could't find in the query function, because the QuestionCursor from this function has 0 rows and there are three questions in the database which meet the criteria. It would be great if you could spot the error.

The query function in my SQLiteAssetHelper, which returns a QuestionsCursor with 0 rows:

```
public QuestionCursor queryUnlearnedQuestions(int chapterId) {
    Cursor wrapped = getReadableDatabase().query
            (TABLE_QUESTIONS,
            null,
            COLUMN_QUESTIONS_CHAPTER_ID + " = ? AND " + COLUMN_QUESTIONS_LEARNED + " = ? ",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(chapterId), String.valueOf(0)},
            null,
            null,
            COLUMN_QUESTIONS_QUESTION_ID + " asc");
    return new QuestionCursor(wrapped);
}
```

The custom CursorWrapper

```
public static class QuestionCursor extends CursorWrapper {
    public QuestionCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Question getQuestion(){
        if(isBeforeFirst()||isAfterLast()) return null;

        Question question = new Question();

        question.setQuestionId(getInt(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_QUESTIONS_QUESTION_ID)));
        question.setCategoryId(getInt(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_QUESTIONS_CHAPTER_ID)));
        question.setDescription(getString(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_QUESTIONS_DESCRIPTION)));
        question.setQuestionText(getString(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_QUESTIONS_QUESTION_TEXT)));
        question.setAnswerText(getString(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_QUESTIONS_ANSWER_TEXT)));
        question.setIsLearned((getInt(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_QUESTIONS_LEARNED)) == 1) ? true:false);
        question.setCorrectAnswers(getInt(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_QUESTIONS_CORRECT_ANSWERS)));
        question.setFalseAnswers(getInt(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_QUESTIONS_FALSE_ANSWERS)));
        question.setLastAnswerDate(new Date(getLong(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_QUESTIONS_LAST_ANSWER_DATE))));

        return question;
    }
}
```

A Singleton calls the function and puts the objects in an ArrayList with a fixed length.

```
public ArrayList<Question> getUnlearnedQuestions(int chapterId, int maxlength) {    
    ArrayList<Question> unlearnedQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();     
    QuestionCursor cursor = mHelper.queryUnlearnedQuestions(chapterId);         

    Log.d(TAG, ""+cursor.getCount()); // returns 0

    for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.getPosition() < maxlength; cursor.moveToNext()){           
            if(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                unlearnedQuestions.add(cursor.getQuestion());   
            }else{
                break;
            }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return unlearnedQuestions;  
}
```

The whole LearnMode Activity, which isn't complete yet.

```
public class LearnModeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static String    EXTRA_CHAPTER_ID = "LearnFragment.chapter_id";  
private static String   TAG              = "LearnModeActivity";     
private static int      LEARN_ARRAY_LENGTH = 7;

private int                 mChapterId;             
private ArrayList<Question> mQuestionList;

private ViewPager           mViewPager;

protected void onCreate(Bundle args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(args);
    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.view_pager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    mQuestionList = ChapterManager.get(this).getUnlearnedQuestions(mChapterId, LEARN_ARRAY_LENGTH);

    Log.d(TAG, "Question List size: "+ mQuestionList.size()); //returns 0

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                    //should return mQuestionList.size(); Changed it to three, otherwise getCount is 0 and I get a blank screen and there is no IndexOutOfBondException
            return 3;


        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            //Indexoutofboundsexception right here
            Question question = mQuestionList.get(pos); 


            return LearnModeFragment.newInstance(question.getQuestionId());
        }
    });

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int index) {
            Question question = mQuestionList.get(index);
            setTitle(question.getQuestionId()+". "+question.getDescription());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }
    });
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you calling these methods?

Comment: I'm using a Singleton to call the method from the database. The function gets the question objects and and puts them in an ArrayList. The singleton method gets called in a Viewpager activity. I'll add the code in a edit in a few seconds.

Comment: Sorry, it took a bit longer to edit the post, because of formatting issues.

Comment: I got it, the mistake is in my Activity. I haven't initialized mChapterId before calling it in the function to get the ArrayList, thus passing null in the function.. But thanks for your help, otherwise it would take a long time until I would look at the Activity.